# Embed Xcode Playground within an application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift, swift-playground

I want to make a Cocoa OS X application where users will be able to input and execute Swift language code within a window in my application. My first thought was to make my own basic IDE, and execute compilation and executing with system calls; however, I'd really like to have the interactive Playground feature.

I did my research and found that I can create Xcode Playground files with embedded documentation, but this raises a question:

> Does the documentation have to be placed above and below the
>   playground, or can I embed a Playground within a container in my HTML
>   code?

The Xcode Playground embedded documentation I speak of [can be found here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/ios-8-interactive-playgrounds/).

Basically, I am looking to embed the Playground in a way that mimics the layout used on CodeAcademy.com

[image]

Is this possible with the Documentation embedded Xcode Playgrounds, or must I recreate an IDE from scratch within my Cocoa application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's [Interactive Learning Document Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/InteractiveLearning.html), the `sections` element of a playground can contain only a flat list of `code` and `documentation` elements interspersed, which is to say **they must be inline** as of writing.

However, you'll notice a message that the top of the guide,

> Warning: This is a specification that is likely to change.

Conclusion: no, but [file a feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Bummer. Could you suggest a method in which this can be best mimicked?

Would it be better to create my own basic IDE within my Cocoa application (is there a way I can add REPL into my own application to mimic playgrounds?), can I embed this Playground window within my application in any way, or something else?

Comment: That's a very broad question...you could certainly execute the `swift` tool in the background, but as for keeping a live connection to a REPL...I doubt the current publicly available LLDB APIs work with Swift, but you could give it a try.

Comment: My question was how I can mimic an application as seen in the image presented in the original post. I understand that I can create the layout and all using OS X Storyboard, but how would I best recreate the code editor section, where the phrase `print "Hello Welcome to Python"` is shown.

I can recreate my own basic IDE, which would basically be a text input field with some fancy features like refractor and code completion, but this would take a TON of work, especially the code completion section. I want to know if there is a better suggestion that for me to "recreate the wheel". 

Any idea?

Comment: Again, too broad for this forum — see [help/on-topic]. Have you tried NSTextView?